# Await on the last method line

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, c#-5.0

Still learning about async-await. I bumped into examples similar to following:

```
public async Task MethodAsync()
{
  await Method01Async();
  await Method02Async();
}
```

What is the purpose of the last await? Method02Async is the last line of MethodAsync method. So there is no any method remainder - no any lines below - no anything to be called in the callback generated by the compiler... Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There actually is a "method remainder" - it completes the `Task` returned by `MethodAsync`.

(The return value of) `Method02Async` is awaited so that `MethodAsync` is not completed until `Method02Async` completes.

If you had:

```
public async Task MethodAsync()
{
  await Method01Async();
  Method02Async();
}
```

Then the `MethodAsync` will (asynchronously) wait for `Method01Async` to complete and then start `Method02Async`. `MethodAsync` will then complete while `Method02Async` may still be in progress.

The way you have it:

```
public async Task MethodAsync()
{
  await Method01Async();
  await Method02Async();
}
```

Means that `MethodAsync` will (asynchronously) wait for `Method01Async` to complete and then (asynchronously) wait for `Method02Async` to complete, and only then will `MethodAsync` complete.

Comment: In particular, imagine if Method02Async were, say, Task.Delay(5000).  It would be exceedingly odd if someone said "await MethodAsync()" and then that task completed *before* the delay completed!

Comment: But isn't that better to write "return Method02Async();" as the last line?

Comment: @duduamar: That wouldn't compile unless you remove the `async` from `MethodAsync`. Which means you'd have to remove the `await` from `Method01Async`, too. A considerable change in behavior.

Comment: @StephenCleary of course you are right. But if that last line was the only line, what is better? return that task (without async method) or async-await?

Comment: @duduamar: In that case, just return the task without the `async`/`await`.