# Understanding "await" usage in async methods

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm running the following code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new Program().Test();
    }
        
    public async Task Test() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("starting...");
        await Test2();
        Console.WriteLine("done!");
        Thread.Sleep(2*1000);
    }
        
    public async Task Test2() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task in delay...");
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
            
}
```

I was expecting the output to be:

```
starting...
task in delay...
done!
```

However, when I run the code, I get:

```
starting...
Task in delay...
```

and the program terminates. Am I missing something? How should I modify the code to get the expected result?

Another question - according to my understanding, using `await` is redundant on the last line in a method, if I remove it, how can I `await` on the method?

Comment: You need to await `Test()` in `Main()`.

Comment: "according to my understanding, using await is redundant on the last line in a method". No, it is not.

Comment: side note: you really shouldn't `Thread.Sleep` on a pool thread, especially when you're in an `async` method - you can just `await Task.Delay(...)` like you do in the other method

Comment: @Klamsi So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247258/await-on-the-last-method-line) is not the same case of mine?

Comment: @MuhammadJabarin it is the same scenario, but the answer doesn't say "the last `await` is redundant" - quite the opposite; it explains *why it is needed*; the point here is that we don't want the other work to just be orphaned off in the ether; we want to asynchronously await the completion of the other work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

Yes; you didn't await `Test`

```cs
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        await new Program().Test();
    }
```

Without that, `Main` would finish immediately as soon as `Test` returns, which will be the first time an incomplete `await` is encountered - the `async` chain unwinds from the `Task.Delay` (which will be incomplete), leaving the rest of the work in `Test`/`Test2` scheduled in the background; since there are no remaining non-background threads, the process exits.

Note that you could *also* remove the `async` and just `return` the task, i.e.

```cs
    public static Task Main()
        => new Program().Test();
```

which will work very similarly, although it changes the semantics a little re synchronous exceptions. If in doubt: `await`.

Comment: I'm getting "does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point".

Comment: @MuhammadJabarin then you're using a very old compiler version; I advise fixing that; you *can* get around this manually, but honestly: just update compiler  - the hack hack hack would be `new Program().Test().Wait();`, but **please** do not get into the habit of calling `Wait()` (or `.Result`) - the number of times that is correct is basically zero

Comment: @Klamsi that would also not stop the process exiting, even if the compiler accepts it; the `Main()` method would return at the first incomplete await point, which means you don't have any non-background threads, which means you're toast; fortunately the compiler doesn't accept it: `error CS4009: A void or int returning entry point cannot be async`

Comment: @Klamsi and the outside is what matters; threads - there are two kinds, background and non-background; the entry-point (usually `Main`) gets launched on a non-background thread; as soon as the entry-point exits, that thread terminates; timers (`Task.Delay`) do not keep a process alive - only non-background threads do that. Even if the `Task.Delay` triggered early: we would resume on a background thread. So in all cases: zero non-background threads, which means: your exe is toast

Comment: @Klamsi also, just to generalize: any time you type the words `async void`, you're *almost certainly doing something wrong*; there is a kinda-sorta excuse for UI callbacks on event-handlers (which is why it even exists), but even then: you should look at that method with deep suspicion, and maybe refuse to go to any parties that it invites you to

Comment: Yes, and as I didn't use it for now I never thought about what happens if you use void for the main() ;)

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks a lot for the explanation. One last question - shouldn't had the `Thread.Sleep(2*1000);` in the `Test` method prevented the thread from finishing, forcing the main threa (`Main`) to wait for 2 seconds before it terminates?

Comment: Ah, it "releases" on the first `await`, I think I got it now.

Comment: @MuhammadJabarin on the first *incomplete* `await`; if an `await` comes back synchronously with an "I already have the answer" result (which it can do), then no unwind or thread-switch happens

Comment: @MuhammadJabarin: If you can invest an hour, this video is worth it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0mcYVxJEl0

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help guys, I appreciate it. @MarcGravell I just want to make sure I get it correctly; if the last instruction in a method is a `return` one, in that case, using `await` or not is the same?

Comment: @MuhammadJabarin the only time you *can* change between `return` and `await` is when there's only a single `await` in the method, on the last line, that returns the exact same shape (`ValueTask[<T>]` etc) that you're returning - and to use `return` instead of `await` you would need to remove the `async` - but no, that isn't *exactly* the same; the difference comes in what happens if the method you're calling throws *synchronously*, specifically an actual throw, not "I'm returning a faulted task"; if you use `async`/`await`, the compiler wraps this up and returns a faulted task; where-as...

Comment: ...if you *don't* use `async`/`await`, this scenario is exposed directly as the synchronous exception; most people would say the `await` outcome is the preferable one, but *in some high volume scenarios*, it is useful to avoid that machinery when it isn't 100% needed, and accept the fact that it may throw rather than return a faulted task; also, the stack-trace details and exception kind may appear subtly different between these two scenarios. As I said previously: if in doubt, `await`